# Text searching Mysql Index

Tags: mysql, performance, full-text-search, indexing

I have a query which is just a few times too slow but I suspect can be greatly improved if I knew how to index it correctly.  I have two tables which get joined and a WHERE clause which have a date comparison on a field from one table and a REGEXP on a field from the other.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id=tbl2.id 
 WHERE tbl1.date_time > now() AND tbl2.name REGEXP '[[:<:]]search[[:>:]]'
```

The date is indexed but the strings which get regexped are not because there are a lot of inserts into that table and I was afraid that indexing the string would slow down the inserts as the indices get updated.  The goal is to find when the given word ("search" in this example) is in the text.  I also didn't do a full text index because it seemed like a waste when there are only a few different words ~2000 that will be searched like this.  If there is a better way to do this process any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your table structure? Also, adding more expressions in your `WHERE` clause to narrow results down might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I came up with rather than actually doing a full text index was to do the processing in an offline script and save the result.  Rather than running this sometimes slow regexp I built a trie like structure which has all the possible values for search in it and when given the texts can tell from look up which ones are there very fast.